# how can I styling cells in Excel by Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I used version 3.9 of Apache POI for generate excel,and this code is correct on this:

```
public CellStyle getCellStyle(XSSFWorkbook workbook){
    CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("###,###"));
    XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
    font.setFontName("Tahoma");
    cellStyle.setFont(font);
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setVerticalAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    return cellStyle;
}
```

but when upgrade to 3.17و These lines have errors:

```
style.setVerticalAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to version 3.17 release note [here](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html), it says "migrate cell alignment constants from CellStyle to HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment enums" use below code instead

```
style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
```